# How to export org to pdf with RTL text including hebrew

Tags: org-export, latex, pdf, odt

I have written a short document in *org* and I have tried to export it to a *PDF* document for printing and readable formatting.
I am facing some issues however since the document should include both **English** and **Hebrew**

trying to export the document using `org-latex-export-to-pdf` leaves me with a left justified file (as opposed to being right justified for Hebrew) and all Hebrew text is excluded.

Something notable that happens is that all hebrew is missing from the file but still shows up as headlines outside of the document itself:

[image: 1]

I will also attach the original org file:

```
* אודות
קובץ זה נועד לשמש בתור חומר עזר לבחינות בתכנות מחשבים ב#C
הקובץ יכלול תכנים כמו הסברים על כל מושגים, תבניות, וכו'

*שימו לב כי הקובץ מרוכז סביב C#*

* תבניות
** (a, b)החלפה בין שני ערכים
#+begin_src csharp
  int a, b, temp;
  temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
#+end_src

** יצירת משתנה עם ערך אקראי
#+begin_src csharp
  Random rnd = new Random();
  // העצם שנוצר כעט אחראי ליצירת ערכים אקראים
  // כעט ניצור משתנה ואליו תעשה השמה של הערך האקראי החדש שניצור
  int num = rnd.Next(1,7);
  // הערך שנקבל במשתנה יהיה מספר בין 1 ל 6
#+end_src
```

although it's optional I would much prefer to right justify all text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [the *enhanced* ODT exporter](https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt) `ox-odt-9.5.3.456.tar` or later (or simply, any version whose date is *later* than this comment's date).

**The *enhanced* ODT backend is not available with standard Emacs or Org mode, and you need to install it separately.  See [Getting Started with ODT export (OpenDocument Text Exporter for Emacs’ Org Mode](https://kjambunathan.gitlab.io/org-mode-ox-odt/Getting-Started-with-ODT-export.html#Installation) for instructions.**

The snippet below has two numbers of `COMMENT`-ed headlines.  If you uncomment and export you will get different outputs as seen below.

I have never used any of the RTL scripts.

Before typing out this reply I have looked at

1. [How to setup LibreOffice Right To Left Hebrew - English - Ask LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-setup-libreoffice-right-to-left-hebrew/14345/5)
2. [Changing back and forth, RTL and LTR - English - Ask LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/changing-back-and-forth-rtl-and-ltr/52739/6)

I have also tried typing the examples in (2) with `LRE`, `LRM`,  `RLE` and `PDF` marks in Emacs, and from what I can see, the behaviour on the LibreOffice side, matches with what the author describes there.

(2) above is about what you type in the Emacs buffer, and the exporter has no control over it.  (1) above is about how the LibreOffice prints the text runs.  So, this response will focus on implementing  (1), with *enhanced* ODT expoter.

That said, I am very much interested in improving the *enhanced* exporter, if there is a need, to support mixed-language texts, atleast the simple cases.   Please file a bug report or start a discussion thread at [The Authoritative fork of Org mode's ODT exporter](https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt#readme)

*(Note: In screenshots below, TOC should be right aligned, but it is NOT because of [LibreOffice Bug#149259: After updating a Table Of Contents, text alignment of toc entries is not preserved](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149259))*

If you want this

[image: Hebrew paragraphs are right aligned, while code blocks are left aligned]

do this

#### Snippet - Add / Remove the `COMMENT`-s to produce different print rendering

```
#+odt_preferred_output_format: pdf

# * COMMENT Align all paragraphs to the Right
* Align all paragraphs to the Right

#+ATTR_ODT: :target "extra_styles"
#+begin_src nxml
<style:style style:name="Standard"
             style:family="paragraph"
             style:class="text"
             style:master-page-name="">
  <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="end"
                              style:justify-single-word="false"
                              style:page-number="auto">
    <style:tab-stops />
  </style:paragraph-properties>
</style:style>
#+end_src

# * COMMENT ... but align ~example~ blocks to the Left
* ... but align ~example~ blocks to the Left

#+ATTR_ODT: :target "extra_styles"
#+begin_src nxml
<style:style style:name="OrgFixedWidthBlock"
             style:parent-style-name="Preformatted_20_Text"
             style:family="paragraph"
             style:master-page-name="">
  <style:paragraph-properties fo:background-color="transparent"
                              fo:border="0.06pt solid #000000"
                              fo:padding="0.049cm"
                              fo:text-align="start"
                              style:justify-single-word="false"
                              style:page-number="auto"
                              style:shadow="none" />
</style:style>
#+end_src

* אודות
קובץ זה נועד לשמש בתור חומר עזר לבחינות בתכנות מחשבים ב#C
הקובץ יכלול תכנים כמו הסברים על כל מושגים, תבניות, וכו'

*שימו לב כי הקובץ מרוכז סביב C#*

* תבניות
** (a, b)החלפה בין שני ערכים
#+begin_src csharp
  int a, b, temp;
  temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;
#+end_src

** יצירת משתנה עם ערך אקראי
#+begin_src csharp
  Random rnd = new Random();
  // העצם שנוצר כעט אחראי ליצירת ערכים אקראים
  // כעט ניצור משתנה ואליו תעשה השמה של הערך האקראי החדש שניצור
  int num = rnd.Next(1,7);
  // הערך שנקבל במשתנה יהיה מספר בין 1 ל 6
#+end_src
```

By un-`COMMENT`-ing you can get these renderings ...

**What you get by default without any custom styles whatsoever**
[image: What you get by default]

**What you get when all paragraphs are aligned to the right**
[image: What you get when all paragraphs are aligned to the right]

Comment: Is there a way to align the Table of Contents itself to the right? (not the end of the world)

Comment: You haven't tried my suggestion ...  See [LibreOffice Bug#149259: After updating a Table Of Contents, text alignment of toc entries is not preserved](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149259)

Comment: For some reason the export is stylized like this https://imgur.com/a/bZLxmiD
I have checked that odt is using the enhanced version.  and the comments you provided are uncommented (unless I misunderstood what to uncomment).

Comment: Also using both comments to align regular text to the right and code to the left does not work, all text is aligned to right

Comment: If a `headline` is `COMMENT`-ed then `nxml` block under it will not take effect. `Standard` style has `fo:text-align="end"` and `OrgFixedWidthBlock` has `fo:text-align="start"` in their definitions.  In your case, the `OrgFixedWidthBlock` definition is not taking effect.  I suggest that you look up for further help in [`COMMENT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Comment-Lines.html) or [Good Resources for learning LibreOffice](https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt#good-resources-for-learning-libreoffice)